# IIS using only one processor on a dual CPU server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis

We are running an HP ProLiant Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and IIS 7.5 on a dual CPU Xeon system (16 cores per CPU).  The web site is a ASP.NET 4.5 running in a App-pool using a a classic managed pipeline.

When I load test our application only one CPU is loaded.  The other stays CPU flat, i.e. it is using 16 cores of available 32.

I checked the Affinity option in the app pool settings in IIS and it is False.

I then checked the Affinity for the w3wp.exe process in the Task Manager and it displayed two processor groups:  "Group 0" and "Group 1".

All cores were checked in "Group 0" but none in "Group 1".  When I tried selecting all in "Group 1" the setting wouldn't save (it just opened up unselected when I checked "Set affinity ..." again.)

Is IIS able to handle dual processors for a single app pool?  Is there a missing setting I need to set? Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear to me if it's using 1 core out of the 32 possible, or using 1 CPU (16 cores). Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: 1 CPU, 16 cores.  The other CPU lies almost  dormant (handling other processes it seems)

Comment: What CPUs does the server have? Are you sure it's not using all physical cores and just not using multiple virtual cores that share a physical core?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with ProLiant servers and HP has issued a BIOS patch to address it:

http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=5379860&docId=emr_na-c04650594&docLocale=en_US

It worked.